# Trying figure out how do implement this search in mongodb the right way

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, word-frequency, keyword-search, database

Right now I imported a huge json file of yelp review into my mongodb database on Linux. I want to implement a right way to search for keywords, so I can look for keyword "UFC" under "text" and "Alcohol: full_bar" under attributes.

This is what I have so far:

```
db.yelp.find({
  $or: [{
    "text": UFC /.*enjoy.*/i
  }, {
    "attributes": Alcohol: full_bar/.*good.*/i
  }]
})
```

This is a sample of my json file:

```
{"time":["Fri-0:2","Sat-0:1","Sun-0:1","Wed-0:2","Sat-1:2","Thu-1:1","Wed-1:1","Sat-2:1","Sun-2:2","Thu-2:1","Wed-2:1","Fri-3:1","Sun-3:3","Thu-4:1","Tue-4:1","Sun-6:1","Wed-6:1","Fri-10:1","Sat-10:1","Mon-11:1","Wed-11:2","Mon-12:1","Sat-12:1","Tue-12:1","Sat-13:2","Thu-13:1","Tue-13:2","Wed-13:2","Fri-14:2","Sat-14:1","Wed-14:1","Fri-15:1","Sat-15:1","Thu-15:1","Tue-15:1","Fri-16:1","Sat-16:2","Sun-16:1","Tue-16:1","Sat-17:3","Sun-17:1","Fri-18:1","Mon-18:1","Sat-18:2","Sun-18:1","Tue-18:2","Wed-18:1","Fri-19:2","Mon-19:1","Sun-19:2","Thu-19:1","Wed-19:1","Mon-20:1","Sun-20:5","Thu-20:1","Tue-20:1","Wed-20:2","Fri-21:2","Sun-21:1","Thu-21:4","Tue-21:1","Wed-21:1","Fri-22:1","Thu-22:1","Fri-23:1","Mon-23:1","Sat-23:3","Sun-23:1","Thu-23:2","Tue-23:1"],"business_id":"7KPBkxAOEtb3QeIL9PEErg","type":"checkin"}
{"time":["Mon-13:1","Thu-13:1","Sat-16:1","Wed-17:1","Sun-19:1","Thu-20:1","Sat-21:1"],"business_id":"kREVIrSBbtqBhIYkTccQUg","type":"checkin"}
{"time":["Thu-0:1","Mon-1:1","Mon-12:1","Sat-16:1"],"business_id":"tJRDll5yqpZwehenzE2cSg","type":"checkin"}
{"time":["Fri-0:1","Sat-0:1","Sun-0:1","Thu-0:1","Wed-0:1","Fri-1:1","Sat-1:1","Tue-1:1","Mon-2:1","Sun-2:1","Thu-2:1","Sat-3:1","Thu-3:1","Wed-3:1","Mon-17:1","Sat-17:1","Sun-17:2","Tue-17:1","Fri-18:1","Mon-18:1","Sun-18:1","Mon-19:1","Mon-20:3","Sat-20:1","Thu-20:1","Mon-21:1","Thu-21:1","Sat-22:3","Sun-22:1","Tue-22:3","Wed-22:1","Sat-23:2","Tue-23:3"],"business_id":"nhZ1HGWD8lMErdn3FuWuTQ","type":"checkin"}
{"time":["Sat-11:1","Fri-13:1","Thu-14:1"],"business_id":"8bY6M2yiWOF2ilfmGS34Fw","type":"checkin"}
{"time":["Mon-0:1","Fri-1:1","Sun-1:1","Tue-1:1","Wed-11:1","Fri-12:1","Tue-12:1","Fri-13:1","Sun-15:1","Thu-16:1","Sat-17:1","Fri-18:1","Sun-18:1","Fri-20:1","Sat-20:2","Sun-20:1","Thu-20:2","Sat-21:1","Thu-21:1","Wed-23:1"],"business_id":"zNVot5_XHsxwfKdiFjk_aA","type":"checkin"}
{"time":["Fri-0:1","Sun-0:1","Wed-0:1","Sun-1:2","Tue-1:2","Sat-2:1","Sat-15:1","Fri-17:2","Sat-17:1","Thu-17:1","Tue-17:1","Wed-17:1","Sat-18:1","Sun-19:1","Thu-19:2","Fri-22:2","Sun-22:2","Thu-22:1","Tue-22:1","Fri-23:1","Sat-23:1","Thu-23:1","Tue-23:2","Wed-
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text) for both `text` and `attributes` fields.

`db.yelp.createIndex({ text: "text", attributes: "text" })`

And the search itself should be performed using the [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator.

`db.yelp.find({ $text: { $search: "UFC \"Alcohol: full_bar\"" } })`

See the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/text-search) for more information.